# building a MacOs app for stressing CPU and may be GPU too

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to build an app for MacOs. I am using appleScript in Xcode 11. I have made a 2 .command files for starting stress and killing stress. Both  the files are in Resources Folder of Xcode Project.  Here's the file code

[Stress.command file]

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
```

[KillStress.command file]

```
Killall dd
```

My AppDelegate.applescript file

```
on stress_(sender)
        display dialog "Started Stressing the CPU"
        do shell script "open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_LUpnjgPso"
        do shell script "open ~/Resources/Stress.command"

        end stress_

    on endstress_(sender)

        do shell script "open ~/Resources/killstress.command"

        end endstress_
```

Now the problem I am facing is I have no clue how to access files from Resources folder.
Please help me

Thanks in adavance

Comment: "how to access" what does this mean?  you need to execute the files?  read them?

Comment: That isn't much of a load generator, but for regular AppleScript you can use StandardAdditions' [path to resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW20), and to get used to navigating the Cocoa documentation, NSBundle's [pathForResource:ofType:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1410989-pathforresource?language=objc) would be a place to start.

Comment: @Richard Barber  i am trying to execute stress.command file on a button click. If i simply write stress command in applescript instead of making a .command file than UI becomes unresponsive

Comment: I need a applescirpt syntax to access Resources folder of Xcode .. or any way through with to access the stress.command file after I compile the app for final release. a command like This - [do shell script "open ~/Resources/Stress.command"] but this doesn't work

Comment: Wondering about your use of the tilde path `~/`